# Multiplying 1x2 and 2x2 matrices in R

Tags: r, matrix, multiplication

I am trying to find out how to simply use R, multiplying a 1x2 and a 2x2 matrix. I can figure out the answer, I just cannot find an example anywhere online referencing a 1x2 and a 2x2 example. I am just trying to get the code so I can understand it. Here are random numbers that I will be using:

[1 2]*[3  4
       5  6]

Code only as I need to understand it; this is not for work or school. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The `matrix()` function makes the matrices and `%*%` indicates matrix multiplication:

```
matrix(data=c(1,2),nrow=1, ncol=2) %*% matrix(data=c(3,4,5,6),nrow=2,ncol=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

John Paul gave a nice concise answer, but I'll add a little bit more explanation for learning purposes.

the `matrix()` function creates a standard matrix. The information is input with the argument `data`. By default the information is recorded by column, to change this use the argument `byrow = T`by this I mean:

If I have 1x2 matrix, let's the numbers are 1 and 2 this is how I put it in:

```
m1 <- matrix(data = c(1,2), byrow = T, ncol = 2)
m1
 [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
```

As you can see, you have a 1x2 matrix, actually a vector.

Now there two more arguments called `nrow` and `ncol` they specify the number of rows and columns.

If I want 2x2 matrix, let's say the numbers are 3,4,5, and 6:

```
m2 <- matrix(data = c(3,4,5,6), nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
m2

    [,1] [,2]
    [1,]    3    5
    [2,]    4    6
```

Remember the data is entered columnwise top to bottom.

Now the multiplication is simple, just use the `%*%` operator

```
m1%*%m2
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   11   17
```

Which yields a 1x2 matrix